# How to change app default theme to a different app theme?

Tags: android, themes

I have an Android app that has a default theme of Holo.Light but I want to change it to Theme.Black.I tried to do this by changing the style tag in the manifest `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` to Theme.Black but it cannot be found.Is there extra steps I have to take in changing the theme?

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Actually you should define your styles in `res/values/styles.xml`. I guess now you've got the following configuration:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"/>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"/>
```

so if you want to use *Theme.Black* then change *AppBaseTheme* parent to `android:Theme.Black` or you could change app style directly in manifest file like this -  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"`. You must be lacking *android* namespace before *style* tag.

You can read more about styles and themes [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles).

Answer (score 6):

To change your application to a different built-in theme, just add this line under application tag in your app's `manifest.xml` file.

Example:

```
<application 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>

<application 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>

<application 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"/>

<application 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"/>
```

If you set style to DeviceDefault it will require min SDK version 14, but if you won't add a style, it will set to the device default anyway.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reference an android style, you need to put "android:" in there

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"
```

If that doesn't solve it, you may need to edit your question with the full manifest file, so we can see more details

Answer (score -6):

Or try to check your mainActivity.xml you make sure that this one
    `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"here`is included

Comment: This is not related to question

Comment: This is not an accessible url