# Placing button in a corner?

Tags: android

Actually im fighting with Layouts and i have problem.When i add button in RelativeLayout, he's not exact in place i want him to be.

[That is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihuVg.jpg)

[That is how i want it to looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm7wj.jpg)

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Thats what i got.So how i can make button be in corner, thats the first question. Second is, how i can delete this blue stuff from top?

xml looks how he looks when start project. I just add button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: remove padding from RelativeLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how i can make button be in corner, thats the first question.

remove this from your `RelativeLayout`

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

you have given padding in your main layout, so this problem occurs

> how i can delete this blue stuff from top?

You can remove that part by changing your project theme, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370719/remove-android-default-action-bar) to remove actionbar.

Comment: Ok that's done. Thanks. What with this blue stuff on top? How i can remove this?

Comment: that blue stuff is called actionbar/titlebar, you can remove it by setting differenct themes

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the blue stuff at the top by changing [theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186235/how-to-change-app-default-theme-to-a-different-app-theme).
Also, make sure none of your containers have margin or padding, because the small space between the border of the screen and your button seems like coming from this.

Comment: I make this screenshot in paint, thats why u can see small spaces betwen ;) Thank u