# Android: Google Play Services 'No Resource' Error

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I use Eclipse to write android code. I created a new android project. When I attempt to import the Google play service library I get the following error:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.    appinvite_styles.xml    /google-play-services_lib/res/values-v11

The following are my API level details:

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

[image]

I downloaded the Google play service via the SDK manager. It is better to say that I downloaded the FULL package of android SDK.

i think API 11 it's problem how can i change it  ?

[image]

How should I resolve this?

i right click the google service library~> android ~> set API 21

That's works fine !
good luck

Comment: I think you have to change the min sdk version to a higher version or change the app theme.

Comment: @RicardoAlexandre: i test
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" /> but still not working ..

Comment: try changing your theme, maybe to base theme? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186235/how-to-change-app-default-theme-to-a-different-app-theme

Comment: If you solved it post the solution in an answer and accept it. Thank you

Comment: @EugenPechanec: Sure ! i post it :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue. I believe you would have imported the google play services library project in your workspace?
It's weird but android wants you to build that project with their latest API. Try to install and change the Project Build Target to Android 6.0(API 23).
Then clean the project and build again.
Errors should go now.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] : i right click the google service library(when i add it to my project )  ~> android ~> set API 21

That's works fine ! good luck

Comment: When you find a solution, do not add [solved] in the title. Instead, accept an answer as a solution.